# torch.load() with error _pickle.UnpicklingError: could not find MARK

Tags: python, pytorch, pickle

in my code,the sentence

```
state = torch.load(best_model_file)
```

reports the following error

```
File "/home/usr/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 367, in load
    return _load(f, map_location, pickle_module)
  File "/home/usr/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 528, in _load
    magic_number = pickle_module.load(f)
_pickle.UnpicklingError: could not find MARK
```

i've tried state.seek(0),but it didnt help.